# What do these values from the ANTLR symbol table mean?

Tags: compiler-construction, antlr

I have dumped the symbol table in antlr and I have a few fields which I am not clear on their meaning. If there is a reference to this, please point me to it. The table has identifier, then starttoken, endtoken, otherinfo.  I have broken it up by group

- 1565614310 is the identifier - I have that
- startToken = [TokenInformation: L:1, charPosInL:8, s:8, e: 11, i: 1]
- endToken =  [TokenInformation: L:1, charPosInL:8, s:8, e: 11, i: 1]
- otherinfo =  [State: 737 - Type: Identifier]

The brackets are mine. 
in startToken i see the line (L:1) and the column (:8) it starts and the corresponding end in endtoken. What do the start (s), end (e) and index (i) mean ? Don't see a rhyme or reason to it.

Otherinfo = what is State ? It doesnt match anything I can see.

Here are a few lines so you can get a feel for the output.

```
1565614310 - [TokenInformation: L:1, charPosInL:8, s:8, e: 11, i: 1] - [TokenInformation: L:1, charPosInL:8, s:8, e: 11, i: 1] - State: 737 - Type: Identifier
783141366 - [TokenInformation: L:3, charPosInL:0, s:17, e: 22, i: 3] - [TokenInformation: L:29, charPosInL:0, s:832, e: 832, i: 3] - State: 777 - Type: PUBLIC
688113407 - [TokenInformation: L:3, charPosInL:0, s:17, e: 22, i: 3] - [TokenInformation: L:3, charPosInL:0, s:17, e: 22, i: 3] - State: 781 - Type: PUBLIC
1638864144 - [TokenInformation: L:3, charPosInL:22, s:39, e: 39, i: 6] - [TokenInformation: L:29, charPosInL:0, s:832, e: 832, i: 6] - State: 798 - Type: LBRACE
```

Thank you

Comment: ANTLR *has/offers* a *symbol table*?   Maybe I'm behind the curve, but ANTLR in the past has been about parsing.   A symbol table is usually a set of maps from identifiers in scopes to descriptive information about the identifier of interest.   The data exhibite by OP appears to location information, not type or scope information.   Happy to be corrected if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes. Its in there. The Definitive Guide has some examples and of course Parr created one of his own on github. So I culled this from various examples. Once the lexing is in progress, this is rather a necesary output. But yes, its in there.

Comment: The symbol table is not directly part of ANTLR4 and there are no "official" ports of it to the other targets. Nonetheless I ported it to C++ and Typescript for my own use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find the code which prints this info, so I can only give an educated guess:

- **L** is obviously the source line
- **s**: could be the start char index of the token for this symbol
- **e**: could be the end char index of the token for this symbol (note: end indices always point to the last char, not the position after that, so a length computation has always to add 1: `length = end - start + 1`.
- **i**: is then the token index for this symbol
- **otherinfo**: contains more details about the token, like the state number of the token and the type.

For the state number: remember, the parsing process is steered by an underlying network with states and transitions: the ATN (augmented transition network).

For completeness:

- The Java (and original) symbol table version is [symtab](https://github.com/antlr/symtab).
- The C++ port can be found in the [MySQL Workbench repository](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/tree/8.0/library/parsers).
- The Typescript port is part of my [Code Completion Core for ANTLR4](https://github.com/mike-lischke/antlr4-c3/blob/master/src/SymbolTable.ts) (antlr-c3).

Note: when I speak of "ports" then this is not really correct. The non Java versions are rather a re-implementation using the basic principles from the Java variant. There are significant differences.